# Artificial Intelligence : A modern Approach (Part V)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I'm currently reading Peter Norvig's Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach (AIMA) to learn the basics of AI (I chose this book after reading about it on the internet and asking a professor of mine if it was a good place to start.

I'm currently at Chapter 7 (first chapter of part 3 - Knowledge and Reasoning) part 4 is Uncertain Knowledge and Reasoning and Part V is about learning (what is the part I'm most interested in right now)

From anyone who's ever used this book as a source of study I'd like to know if I could read part 5 (to start learning what is my current goal) in parallel with parts 3 and 4 (I want to read all the chapters in the book, cause I think it'll just add up to my knowledge base). Can I do this? Will I be "wasting more time" than gaining ?

Thanks in advance. PS: my current goal really is machine learning and that's why I'm insecure, I' don't know if it's worth reading the "learning" part before the knowledge part

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your ultimate goal? Are you reading it just to get some background in theoretical AI or you want to apply certain concepts somewhere. If the answer is yes, then which domain (Internet Algorithms, Gaming, Analytics etc.) you want to apply AI?

Comment: You should read a different book if you're interested in machine learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not impossible, but difficult.

Just as an isolated example, if you're trying to do machine learning on some uncertain environment (which you often are) it helps immensely to have learned the notations, the assumptions, the constraints, etc., of uncertain environments... which are presented in section IV.

I think if you start with Section V, you'll find yourself flipping back to Section IV and possibly III quite often.  You should probably at least skim (detailed skim) those sections to get a feel for the major conclusions are, so you know where to look when you do need to flip back.

Comment: I see, I'm reading faster the first chapter (and probably will the next few) of part III because I've already taken logic in Uni so I don't need to read more than once most parts as it's mostly "reminding", thanks for the heads up, I'll just finish parts III and IV then, prolly part four will ask more of me.

Answer (score 0):

A (learning) book is often written in a certain sequence. It starts with chapter 'one' and ends in chapter 'last'. Surely you can start at the end and then work backwards. Then you'll have Star Wars all over again ;-). I have the book and I just went from first to last.

Though I can't really recall all the chapters. But I would just read 3,4 and then 5. You have to read them anyway and it won't really take that long to read them either. Unless you are in a hurry.